# Bitwise operation with grouping using Linq

Tags: linq, bit-manipulation

I have a data like

```
public class PermList
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public int BitMaskedPermission { get; set; }

    public List<PermList> TestData()
    {
        List<PermList> theList = new List<PermList>();
        PermList sample1 = new PermList {BitMaskedPermission = 15, GroupId = 3, ModuleId = 2, UserId = 1};
        theList.Add(sample1);
        PermList sample2 = new PermList { BitMaskedPermission = 2, GroupId = 3, ModuleId = 1, UserId = 1 };
        theList.Add(sample2);
        PermList sample3 = new PermList { BitMaskedPermission = 48, GroupId = 2, ModuleId = 2, UserId = 1 };
        theList.Add(sample3);
        return theList;
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like to apply OR to BitMaskedPermissions with grouping ModuleId. Here is what I would like to get;

[image]

How can I achieve this with using Linq.

TIA.

Answer (score 4):

When you have an aggregation operation to perform that isn't one of the built-in ones (`Sum`, `Max` etc), you have to turn to `Aggregate`, which is more verbose but also much more powerful. Here, you want

```
var data = TestData();
var grouped = 
    from permList in data
    group permList by new { permList.UserId, permList.ModuleId } into g
    select new { // or a named class if you have one
        g.Key.UserId,
        g.Key.ModuleId,
        BitMaskedPermission 
            = g.Aggregate(0, (acc, curr) => acc | curr.BitMaskedPermission)
    };
```

Here, we pass `Aggregate` a function which takes the **accumulator** `acc` and the **current value** `curr`, and bitwise ORs them to get the ongoing accumulator value.

If you prefer the method-chaining syntax, it would look like (courtesy of [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338068/chris)):

```
var grouped = PermList.TestData()
    .GroupBy(x=> new{x.UserId, x.ModuleId})
    .Select(x=> new {
        x.Key.UserId, 
        x.Key.ModuleId, 
        mask = x.Aggregate(0, (acc, curr)=>acc|curr.BitMaskedPermission)}
     )
```

Comment: And since I'd done the thing in the other form I present the method equivalent of that: `PermList.TestData().GroupBy(x=> new{x.UserId, x.ModuleId}).Select(x=> new {x.Key.UserId, x.Key.ModuleId, mask = x.Aggregate(0, (acc, curr)=>acc|curr.BitMaskedPermission)})`. Feel free to edit it into your answer if you want (or modify and edit or whatever

Comment: Also I think your Aggregate is wrong. You need g.Aggregate(0,(acc, curr) => acc | curr.BitMaskedPermission) I think (ie setting teh accumulator default to 0 and using the bitmask, not the PermList
 object.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the catch. btw if you are happy to use the first element of the sequence as the initial accumulator value (as we are here), you [don't need to explicitly supply it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I've just checked and you do need the initial accumulator. Without it uses the first element of the sequence but this is of course a PermList object whereas we need an int...

Comment: Although AakashM answer is correctly points the solution and a good explanation of aggregation, Chris' update is needed to solve the problem. Thanks both.

Comment: @bsaglamtimur: no problem. I lilke to play around with more complicated linq stuff. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
PermList p=new PermList();
    var result= (
        from test in p.TestData()
        group test by new{test.UserId,test.ModuleId} into g
        select new
        {
            g.Key.UserId,
            g.Key.ModuleId,
            BitMaskedPermission= g.Sum (x =>x.BitMaskedPermission )
        }
    );
```

Comment: This would indeed work on the sample data, but suppose `BitMaskedPermission` were `15` for both the `ModuleId` `2` rows: this code would give `30`, which would be wrong.

Comment: sum won't necessarily do what you want. If you have two bitmasks that are both 32 then the outcome of combining them should be 32, not 64 as sum would give.